# Whatsapp local backup

Tags: backup

I recently installed again whatsapp in my new smartphone android but the local backup doesn't work automatically. Today I pressed back up for the google drive backup and it also included the local backup. But for the past weeks whatsapp never did the local backup automatically. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your phone is a bit aggressive about killing the background tasks. So, WhatsApp is unable to wake up the phone at its usual 1-2AM slot to perform a backup. A lot of phones are doing this to ensure a better battery backup and standby.

Do note that notifications may still flow even when WhatsApp is not allowed to do tasks related to backup in the background. But most of the times, they are either delayed or only show up when you first turn on the phone display in the morning.

Comment: Thanks. In case you are right is there something that I might do for this issue?

Comment: Depends on which phone do you have. Most phones do allow you to reduce how aggressivly the phone kills the apps. Check in Settings > battery if you have a setting related to background activity. Another (usually different from each other) should be in: Settings > Apps > WhatsApp > Battery > Don't optimize.

Comment: Thanks. In my new smartphone under 'battery' it says 'power saving exclusions' but I think it is the same thing.

Comment: I tried to exclude power saving features but it didn't to the local backup automatically. Any other possible reason?

Comment: Not sure. WhatsApp not running in the background is the only practical reason for it to not backup automatically. I don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: I didn't add that my phone is always switched off. Maybe this is the reason whatsapp doesn't back up automatically in local storage?

Comment: Well, then that makes sense. You're not having WhatsApp running during its scheduled cron which takes an automatic backup. There's no way to manually assign a time when WhatsApp takes a backup. So, you either have WhatsApp running at that time (phone be turned on) or do manual backups.